# Can't login into LUIS portal

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

When I try to login into the LUIS portal (https://www.luis.ai/), doesn't matter if it is the preview or the default, after entering my credentials I am redirected to the home page (luis.ai) with an error message:

*"An error ocurred while authenticating your account with Microsoft Azure Active Directory. Click here to download the error log and send it when contacting support."*

When I download the error log, the file is basically empty:

```
    "Error": "",
    "ErrorDescription": ""
}
```

I am trying to log in with my personal account (@outlook.com), the same account I use for my Azure subscription.

[Print of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSp0G.png)

Someone faced this  problem too? Is there a workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The portal definitely doesn't win awards for "5 nines" up-time. I had some issues yesterday, getting the classic asp.net "custard" screen. I'd suggest just giving it 20-30 minutes, then trying again.

Comment: Is the portal working for you now, or still giving issues?